# How does special relativity affect absorption spectra?

Tags: special-relativity, material-science, spectroscopy

Metal reflects radio waves but absorbs UV.

Suppose a spaceship was burning towards Earth near the speed of light and a dish on Earth sent out a radar pulse. From Earth's perspective, the photons reach the ship as radio waves and should reflect back. From the ship's perspective, the photons are Doppler shifted to UV and should be absorbed.

What actually happens? My guess is that material properties also change near light speed, so that from the Earth's perspective radio waves are now absorbed.

Comment: > *"From Earth's perspective, the photons reach the ship as radio waves and should reflect back."* No, we only have experience with metal walls that are at rest or moving with non-relativistic speeds. Thus the proper way to analyze the process is in the ship frame. Thus if the waves are UV in ship's frame, they will get absorbed.

Comment: @JánLalinský Interesting. So there could be something that changes, but we don't know exactly what it is?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Interaction of radio waves with relativistic wall will simply be different then interaction of radio waves with wall at rest, and we know this because we know how the interaction looks like in ship's frame.

Comment: It's the "simply" part I want to know more about. Yes we know that the two frames must agree, but I want to know why. Unless that is simply unknown.

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear. Atoms in a moving wall have different velocity than atoms in stationary wall. Moving atoms interact differently than stationary atoms, due to their different velocity and correspondingly different interaction with external EM field. Analyzing this interaction in a frame where atoms move relativistically is unusual, because it is simpler to do in the frame where atoms are at rest. But it can be done and results are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is correct:

Observer moving with the rockets finds the oncoming waves are UV so they are absorbed.

Therefore they are indeed absorbed and all observers must agree this.

It follows that Earth observer finds that reflective properties of a fast-moving metal sheet are different from those of a non-moving metal sheet.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually somewhat simpler than you are thinking: in relativity there is a relativistic Doppler effect, so both frames agree that the photons interact with the spaceship as ultraviolet.

Comment: "Interact as ultraviolet." That's what I don't get. Until the moment of collision, Earth sees the photons as radio. What is it about the scattering process that makes it UV?

Comment: The Doppler effect is what makes it UV.  You know that thing where when you're moving towards a stationary source of sound, and I on the ground can predict that the wavefronts hitting you, hit you at a higher frequency because from my perspective *you're moving into them*? Turns out time dilation doesn't erase this effect completely and you get a simple formula for the blueshift.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say pair of wires is connected to an AC-generator that produces 100 V at 10 Hz.

A pair of multimeter probes slides along the pair of wires towards the generator at speed 0.5 c. The multimeter measures 150 V at 15 Hz.

---

Let's say an AC-generator at the center of a carousel produces 100 V at 10 Hz.

A multimeter connected to the generator rides along the carousel at speed 0.5 c. The multimeter measures 150 V at 15 Hz.

So, what happens is that an artificial gravity field, or elastic collision with matter, changes the electromagnetic wave. From a radio-wave to an UV-wave, for example.

In the spaceship example the change of the EM-wave and the absorption of it occur simultaneously, that's why it's a bit confusing.

(The calculation of the change of the EM-wave is here a non-relativistic approximation)